# Como esconder um botão no Ionic / Angular após ele ser clicado com ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5, ionic

Tenho um botão, normal, com um ng-click chamando uma função:

```
<button class="button button-full button-balanced" ng-click="fechaPedido(pedido.observacao )">
        FINALIZAR PEDIDO
    </button>
```

Gostaria que, depois de clicado o botão fosse desativado até a função ser concluída. Porque os usuários ficam clicando no botão e repetindo as ações dele.

Ou há outra forma?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi acrescentando $ionicLoading.show(); na função já de inicio e $ionicLoading.hide(); ao final da função.